# Docker Container unable to Connect to ip on Host Machines Network

Tags: docker, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, docker-container

I have a system of three small Spring Boot apps, each to serve a different purpose, which contain REST endpoints. The three apps are meant to all work off of the same database (MariaDB). Right now, the system works as four separate dockers. Three docker containers for the three apps, and a fourth container for the MariaDB (based on MariaDB Docker image). All three app containers connect to the database container using the --link network pattern.

Each of the app dockers were launched from the same image, using:

```
docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 --link mariadb:mariadb javaimage /bin/bash
```

This docker system currently works as expected. All three apps can call the MariaDB, each app is accessible from the host machine via REST calls by calling http://localhost:8080/pathToEndpoint. The project has recently expanded and a new requirement has been added. We are using Netflix Eureka as a service lookup point, which should in the future help allow these Docker's to be deployed anywhere with minimal changes needed to the software calling the Docker's. Netflix Eureka requires me to effectively "check in" when the app is launched. This is all handled by Spring Boot itself, so when the app is launched this "check in" is apart of the startup process. The Eureka server is on the same network as the host machine, and for the time being is being accessed via an ip address. If the Spring Boot applications running this Eureka check-in component are launched directly on the host machine, everything works as expected. The app makes a successful call to the Eureka server and notify it of the app's existence. If I run the same app within a Docker container on the same host machine, this fails as the connection is refused. Upon investigation I found I could not even ping the ip address of the Eureka server from within the Docker container, explaining why it is failing. I continued a little further into testing what does and does not work, and found I can ping external sites such as google without a problem, but any internal to my network servers are un-reachable when I try to ping them from within the Docker container.

Therefore my question is, what network configuration I am missing to cause this? I recognize that Docker has quite a lot of network configuration options, but I have not been able to find someone with a similar issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Seems that there is a long running issue. Please see Docker github https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1143

Comment: can you include details about the network set up? can you show the actual ip addresses on the host, and the host running the service. I would also be interested in seeing any sort of trace route that you could produce. The ip addresses of the containers in question would also be handy. It is expected that any ip address that the host can reach can also be reached by containers running on that host.